Difference between world-normal calculated by sampling view-normal texture and world-normal texture
I have a custom renderer feature that create normal texture and using that.
Normal texture can be view or world space.
If I create view space normal texture and sample with the uv node of the full screen shader graph,
then transform that normal to world space(by unity_CameraToWorld or UNITY_MATRIX_I_V), and compare that with world space normal texture, but they are different(The opposite is also different).
I use an orthographic camera rotated x 30, y 45. Could it be related?
view normal texture to world normal

world normal texture

Add detail: Normal texture created by just normal node in shader graph, So I can create world or view space normal texture.
In my custom renderer feature, Using this shader graph, create normal texture and set this texture to another full screen shader graph's property.
In the full screen shader graph, Normal textures are generated properly and sample this texture to get r,g,b as vector3 ViewSpaceNormal. Then doWorldSpaceNormal = mul((float3x3)unity_CameraToWorld, ViewSpaceNormal). I think, the UNITY_MATRIX_I_V and unity_CameraToWorld matrices seem to be different from the expected view to world matrices in full screen shader graph.
I expected that the view normal texture sampled and changed to world normal, is the same with world normal texture.
If you need additional information, please let me know.

Hey! It's worth attaching the code of normal map generation as well as a shader with what you draw.

I added detail,  If need any more information, please let me know. Thank you.

It's crucial that vec4 that you multiply by the matrix must have 0.0 for last component (w). Also the camera-to-world transformation may include scaling, so this scaling must be uniform (same for xyz), and afterwards you need to renormalize the vector

I use vector3 as normal vector and use 3x3 matrix. I edited for adding this info.

Just curious, can you try WorldSpaceNormal = normalize(mul(ViewSpaceNormal, (float3x3)unity_CameraToWorld))

Here is the result. https://ibb.co/PMZmVR0.

This seems to be working, the colors are brighter, looks more like gamma difference (linear vs srgb)

I have no understanding of color space conversion. I don't know why it happened automatically. Do you have any resources or advice on this?

I'm not sure myself, it depends on the color space of the source texture, and the destination texture, as well as project settings. Maybe a good starting link is this

Problem is the color format of normal texture. In my case, After change the color format to ARGB Half/Float, It is working well.

So just for the future visitors, you need to multiply the normal vector by the matrix from the other side than usual:
WorldSpaceNormal = normalize(mul(ViewSpaceNormal, (float3x3)unity_CameraToWorld));

